# ¿Como puedo ejecutar una web api o endpoint cada cierto tiempo automaticamente en asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Quiero ejecutar un endpoint o ruta de un controlador cada cierto tiempo (10) minutos, para ir monitoreando unos logger de otro programa. como logro hacer eso?

El programa lo estoy haciendo en **asp.net core** 3.0 y es una web api.

saludos

por ejemplo:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("delete")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Mail>> Delete()
        {
            foreach(var u in dbContext.Mails)
            {
                dbContext.Remove(u);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Ok(dbContext.Mails.ToList());
        }
```

hacer que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo

Comment: coloca algo de codigo que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que otra aplicacion la llame, debes programar esa otra aplicacion que consuma el servicio, revisa httpClient

Comment: Otro software debe llamar a tu servicio?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es lanzar Background Tasks, en ASP.NET Core (a partir de la versión 2.1) están los Hosted Services para esto, así que puedes ejecutar funciones cada cierto tiempo, una forma muy básica de hacerlo es así:

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

En el método DoWork pones la lógica que quieres implementar (llamar a un endpoint, método, etc). Te recomiendo que mires la documentación de Microsoft en este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)